# Calculating Inverse function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

Please help me with the following question:
Calculate, if possible, the inverse of the following functions:

(i)   $f(x) = (2x - 2)^5$

(ii)  $f(x) = (2x - 3)/4$

(iii) $f(x) = x^2 + 1,$ for $ x \geq 0$.

Comment: Welcome! We'd be glad to help you, but here are a few pointers: (1) Please limit your requests to one question per post. Ideally, choose the one that's troubling you most. Hopefully, help on that one question will give you the tools you need to answer the others, *on your own*. Also, please share in your post what your thoughts are, e.g., how you think you might approach the one question you decide to ask. That helps us target our answers to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

For each of your functions, ensure that they are bijective, assuming the first two functions are such that $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, and the third function, restricted to $f: \mathbb R_{x\geq 0} \to \mathbb R_{x \geq 0}$.

Your functions are bijective, as so defined, but it's important to know that an inverse function exists if and only if a function is bijective, or more correctly, we can find an inverse function when the domain and codomain are limited in a way so that the inverse of a function can be defined, when that's possible.

I'll help you along with the first question, using a standard method you can use for most problems of this type.

$$f(x) = y =(2x - 2)^5$$

(i) Solve for $x$: Express the function as a function of $y$.

$$\begin{align} y = (2x - 2)^5 &\iff \sqrt[\large 5] y = 2x - 2 = 2(x - 1) \\ \\
&\iff \frac{\sqrt[\large 5] y}{2} = x - 1 \\ \\
& \iff x = \frac{\sqrt[\large 5] y}{2} + 1\end{align}$$

(ii) Now, exchange $x$ for $y$: $$f^{-1}(x) = y = \frac{\sqrt[\large 5] x}{2} + 1$$

(iii) Double check to ensure that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$, since the composition of a function and its inverse is equivalent to the identity function that maps x to x.

Comment: Thanks, @Amzoti - I was debating about whether or how much to answer!

Comment: @amWhy: I always struggle with that too!